# Parsing Error in XML : not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, parse-error

While I was preprocessing Korean corpus, I got this **parsing error**.

File"/~/~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1320, in XML
parser.feed(text)

File "", line unknown
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 30

I think I need to do something with the file name.. but I have no clue. I'm in a real hurry. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: File "<string>", line unknown 
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 30 is the whole line

Comment: A well formed xml file has only one root tag.  When a xml has an array of tags at root it is not well formed.  Many xml (especially feeds from server) are not well formed.  To read files that are not well formed you need to use an XmlReader like following :             XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("filename", settings);